# Ref count of ATL COM object in C# client not going down to Zero even with FinalReleaseComObject of interface pointer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, atl

I have developed a simple atl COM object and have created connectionpoint. The comobject of the interface type is the parameter in the sink function. I have put break point at the fire event in connection point and also at the atlcom.h InternalAddRef/InternalRelease. Just before fire event number of references is 1 but by the time it reaches sink function in C# it increases to 2 and as soon as it gets into C# delegate it becomes 3. When I call FinalReleaseComObject for interface it decreases to 1 from 3 but not to 0 and thus Object destructor not getting called and creating leak. please help me understand how to get the ref count to 0 and avoid leak

```
ret = p_IHUSNVRLyrEvents->OnLivePacket(Packet);//RefCount=1;From the connection point


Ref Count = 1
>   atl100.dll!AtlInternalQueryInterface()  + 0x9f bytes    
>   HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObjectRootEx<ATL::CComMultiThreadModel>::InternalAddRef()  Line 2622   C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObject<CPacket>::AddRef()  Line 2870   C++
    atl100.dll!AtlInternalQueryInterface()  + 0x42 bytes    
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObjectRootBase::InternalQueryInterface(void * pThis, const ATL::_ATL_INTMAP_ENTRY * pEntries, const _GUID & iid, void * * ppvObject)  Line 2453 + 0x18 bytes   C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!CPacket::_InternalQueryInterface(const _GUID & iid, void * * ppvObject)  Line 111 + 0x3a bytes  C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObject<CPacket>::QueryInterface(const _GUID & iid, void * * ppvObject)  Line 2884  C++
Ref Count = 2

>   HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObjectRootEx<ATL::CComMultiThreadModel>::InternalAddRef()  Line 2622   C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObject<CPacket>::AddRef()  Line 2870   C++
Ref Count = 3
>   HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComMultiThreadModel::Decrement(long * p)  Line 359    C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObjectRootEx<ATL::CComMultiThreadModel>::InternalRelease()  Line 2629 + 0x9 bytes  C++
    HUSNVRLayer.dll!ATL::CComObject<CPacket>::Release()  Line 2873 + 0xb bytes  C++
Ref Count = 2

When i reach the .Net Code and enter inside the refcount is 3
```

Comment: If you see the documentation for FinalReleaseComObject: releases all references to a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) by setting its reference count to 0. This does not guarantee the release of the underlying com object. Can you see the stack trace in InternalAddRef? This may tell you who is referencing you com object

Comment: As per documentation the ref count should become Zero by calling FinalReleaseComObject but it is still 1 while debugging atlcom.h but the FinalReleaseComObject returned zero

Comment: @oguz I am confirming this by keeping breakpoint on FinalReleaseComObject and on hitting that put a break point on InternalRelease. On entering internal release I can see ref count was 3 and it decremented till 1 and exited (ideally the ref count should have reduced till 0.. Object's destructor getting called is at COM's control but ref count to Zero should happen right?

Comment: My crystal ball says that IConnectionPoint;;Unadvise() isn't being called.  In other words, you forgot to unsubscribe the event handler.  Reference count problems should never be "fixed" with Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject, that just hides a bug.

Comment: That's why I would check the stack trace in InternalAddRef, not in InternalRelease. Or both, and compare the adding / releasing stack traces. This may tell you which adding stack trace is not releasing you COM object

Comment: @OguzOzgul when even when i unsubscribed by using -= in C# code and adding a break point in InternalRelease/Release, i can see it is not triggered. Also have updated the stack information when the values are incremented/decremented till the code in C# is reaced

Comment: Please [Go through this](http://jpassing.com/2009/03/26/rcw-reference-counting-rules-com-reference-counting-rules/). I think it may be very helpful

Comment: My apologies, i reviewed the code and figured out that a ComPtr was used to refer the COM Object but was not detached hence the ref count was still not dropping. After fixing the dereferencing the ComPtr the ref count is now managed well.